# Restart PC with a custom menu

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I want to restart remote machines with a custom menu. I want the users to cancel restart and restart to continue if the users does not answer for 5 minutes. Please advise.

Comment: You may also want to ask this on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the command line with the `shutdown -i` command.  This brings up the GUI where you can add computers to send the shutdown command to.  You can also set a timeout for how long the user has to cancel the shutdown/restart process (in your case 300 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will point you in the right direction.  Windows [Systems Management Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229113) (SMS, now called [System Center Configuration Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/configurationmanager/en/us/sms.aspx)) has these capabilities.  I don't admin the desktops here (I'm primarily the Unix/Linux admin), but I know our Windows guys use exactly this for exactly what you are asking.